SimpleSamlPHP Admin Page 404 Not Found Nginx
I am trying to hit the admin page of simplesamlphp on an Azure app service running php 8.2 on Linux. Mediawiki 1.39.7 is installed in wwwroot/wiki and simplesamlphp 2.2.1 in wwwroot/wiki/var. I keep getting a 404 not found error when I try to hit https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/wiki/simplesaml/index.php or https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/wiki/simplesaml/admin/index.php. I am using an alias (below) and actual paths in both cases are:
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/wiki/var/simplesamlphp/public/index.php
https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/wiki/var/simplesamlphp/public/admin/index.php
Here is my server config:
 server {   
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;

    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com myapp.azurewebsites.net;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory

    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

   location ^~ /simplesaml {
        alias /var/simplesamlphp/public;

        location ~^(?<prefix>/simplesaml)(?<phpfile>.+?\.php)(?<pathinfo>/.*)?$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$phpfile;

        # Must be prepended with the baseurlpath

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $pathinfo if_not_empty;

        }
    }
}

